# Finding help for QGIS 3.0?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, documentation

Where do I find the help files for QGIS 3.0?

The program links to the version 2.8 help files instead of the current version. There seem to be major differences between the two, and I don't want to ask a million simple questions here (I'm new to QGIS) if I can look them up somewhere.

Answer (score 7):

QGIS documentation is updated for long term releases (LTR). QGIS 3.0 is not LTR. The next LTR will be 3.4. You can find the current status, i.e. latest version of the documentation at https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/

Answer (score 3):

Since there isn't one place to go for QGIS 3.0 help, here are links to some useful resources.

- [User manual for the previous version of QGIS (2.18)](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/)
- [Changelog for QGIS 3.0 (list of changes, new features and updates)](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog30/)

Blog posts about new features in QGIS 3.0:

- https://anitagraser.com/2018/02/21/resources-for-qgis3/
- https://www.birdseyeviewgis.com/blog/2018/2/22/my-favorite-features-of-qgis-30to-date
- https://north-road.com/2017/12/24/24-days-of-qgis-3-0-features/
- https://gisgeography.com/qgis-3/

And of course, [GIS Stackexchange - questions tagged QGIS 3.0](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-3.0)

Comment: There is a good QGIS 3.0 for professionals 10 hour course on Udemy. Not expensive and wirth every penny: https://www.udemy.com/qgis-for-gis-professionals/learn/v4/overview